# How to copy files from windows virtual machine to ubuntu host machine?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have ubuntu installed in my work laptop and windows installed in my virtualbox. I installed windows in virtual machine so that I can download origin games on it. I want to copy those origin game files form the windows virtual machine to my ubuntu main host so that I can copy it from ubuntu to my gaming pc later. How should I do it?

Comment: Create a shared folder that both your guest and host can use.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: The build-in help of VirtualBox is quite good at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Installing [guest additions](https://itsfoss.com/virtualbox-guest-additions-ubuntu/) for VBox should sort you out.

After install, just make a shared folder in the VBox settings for your VM and it will show as a normal drive in file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Install sshfs and winfsp on Windows guest and mount host $HOME directory as a drive and copy files there.

Comment: Details: https://superuser.com/questions/1423371/sshfs-remote-directory-mounting-syntax

Comment: Totally unnecessary, shared folders work well...